# Stability of Fokker plank solutions with drift not coming from potential: Lyapunov analysis

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, elliptic-pde

Consider the FP equation on two dimensional space:

$\dfrac{\partial{\rho(x,y,t)}}{{\partial t}}+u(x,y)\dfrac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}+v(x,y)\dfrac{\partial\rho}{\partial y}=D\Delta\rho(x,y,t)$.

It is known that if the advection $\mathbf{V(x,y)}=[u(x,y) \:\: v(x,y)]^T$ can be derived from a potential $P$, then the FP equation has an asymptotic solution which can be analytically solved. Relatedly, it can be shown that a Lyapunov functional exists, analytically described, which proves the global stability of this asymptotic solution. One specific case is when the resulting $\mathbf{V}$ is divergence free: e.g. $\mathbf{V(x,y)}=\nabla P(x,y)$,

My question is : Can we handle the question of global stability for the case when the advection cannot be derived from a potential function. ? I am looking for any results regarding finding Lyapunov functions in such case.